# Fetching data from MongoDB in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I am new to Sails.js. I am trying to fetch data from my Mongo Db database "TestDB", I have a collection name "Components", so I created a Model named Components whcih contains the attributes of my colection

**Components.js**

```
module.exports = {

 attributes: {
    TaskId: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    CompName: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    InitialAttr: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    Value: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
};
```

**ComponentsController.js**

```
module.exports = {
    GetComponentList : function(req, res){
        Components.find({ CompName: 'ImageComponent'}).exec(function(err, data) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                res.json(data);  
            });
    }
};
```

**Route:**

```
'/comp' : {
        controller: 'components',
        action: 'GetComponentList'
    }
```

The above query executes fine in MongoVUE returning the dataset, but returns

```
[]
```

in Sails.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Waterline ORM expects all database tables / collections to be lowercased.  I'm guessing if you looked in your Mongo database you'd see there are now two collections: `Components` and `components`.  If you don't care about the existing data in your db you can just delete the `Components` collection.  Otherwise you can point your model at the existing collection using the [`tableName` property](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html?q=tablename):

```
module.exports = {

  tableName: 'Components',

  attributes: {
    TaskId: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    ...etc...
  }

}
```